# How to union two cte statements in sql with declare ERROR :Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using  CTE for union two columns in sql.
If I am executing these two queries it is working fine .
But I want to make union of these two for more simpler O/P.

I am getting compile time error :

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

can anyone tell me hoe to achieve union with cte

```
DECLARE @Inward DATETIME
SET @Inward = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT 0 AS TheMonth 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TheMonth + 1 
FROM cte
WHERE TheMonth < 5
) 
SELECT  
cte.TheMonth,
isnull(sum(qty),0) as inward 
FROM 
cte 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_GIN_Master as g 
ON accept_date >= DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth, @Inward) AND accept_date < DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth + 1, @Inward)

UNION all 

DECLARE @Outward DATETIME
SET @Outward = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 0 AS TheMonthO 
UNION ALL
SELECT TheMonthO + 1 
FROM cte 
 WHERE TheMonthO < 5
) 

SELECT  isnull(sum(quantity),0) as outward 
FROM 
cte 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
RS_Sell_Order_Master as s 
ON del_date >= DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonthO, @Outward) AND del_date < DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonthO + 1, @Outward) and isDelivered = 1
left outer join RS_Sell_Order_Mapping as sm on sm.sell_order_no = s.sell_order_no
```

Comment: thank you very much Mr. Sgeddes And DigitalDNA. I really appreciate Your effort. My issue is resolved but I sm getting the o/p for both of the table in the single column & i want it in the diffrent column's what should i do???? to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to begin.

- You cannot use `declare` statements inside of `union` statements.
- `Union` statements must return the same number of columns.
- `Common table expressions` should only be defined at the beginning of your statement.
- Your `Sum` aggregate needs a `group by` to return each month.

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @Inward DATETIME
DECLARE @Outward DATETIME

SET @Inward = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
SET @Outward = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

WITH cte AS 
(
   SELECT 0 AS TheMonth 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT TheMonth + 1 
   FROM cte
   WHERE TheMonth < 5
) 
SELECT  
   cte.TheMonth,
   isnull(sum(qty),0) as inward,
   null as outward
FROM 
   cte 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_GIN_Master as g 
          ON accept_date >= DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth, @Inward) 
         AND accept_date < DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth + 1, @Inward)
GROUP BY cte.TheMonth
UNION all 
SELECT  
   cte.TheMonth,
   null as inward,
   isnull(sum(quantity),0) as outward 
FROM 
   cte 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master as s 
          ON del_date >= DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonthO, @Outward) 
         AND del_date < DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonthO + 1, @Outward) and isDelivered = 1
      left outer join RS_Sell_Order_Mapping as sm on 
          sm.sell_order_no = s.sell_order_no     
GROUP BY cte.TheMonth
```

Comment: thank you very much Mr. Sgeddes . I really appreciate Your effort. My issue is resolved but I sm getting the o/p for both of the table in the single column & i want it in the diffrent column's what should i do???? to achieve this

Comment: @Hardik -- my post above will return 2 columns, one for month, and one for the sum of quantity.  The other post will not return any results.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right sgeddes, But I want the o/p as inward & outward column should be different How will it be possible Sir.

Comment: @Hardik -- do you mean you want to add a 3rd column to the results, where it contains the words `inward` or `outward`?  Or do you want an `inward` column by itself and an `outward` column by itself?

Comment: yup I want inward column and outward column by itself

Comment: @Hardik -- I added the 3rd column to the output.  If you want those grouped together, then it will take a little bit more work on your part.  You won't need the union, but rather you should sum your quantities in a couple of subqueries and join accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54408/discussion-between-hardik-and-sgeddes).

Answer (score 2):

Ha! I'm looked it today because i had the same question. You must declare the first CTE with the "WITH" Keyword and every CTE you need, just separate it with a comma.

**EDIT from sgeedes Query above**

```
    DECLARE @Inward DATETIME
DECLARE @Outward DATETIME

SET @Inward = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
SET @Outward = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

WITH cte AS 
(
   SELECT 0 AS TheMonth 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT TheMonth + 1 
   FROM cte
   WHERE TheMonth < 5
) 
SELECT TheMonth,sum(Inward) as InWard, sum(OutWard) as OutWard
FROM
(
SELECT  
   cte.TheMonth,
   isnull(sum(qty),0) as inward,
   0 as outward
FROM 
   cte 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_GIN_Master as g 
          ON accept_date >= DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth, @Inward) 
         AND accept_date < DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth + 1, @Inward)
GROUP BY cte.TheMonth
UNION all 
SELECT  
   cte.TheMonth,
   0 as inward,
   isnull(sum(quantity),0) as outward 
FROM 
   cte 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master as s 
          ON del_date >= DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonthO, @Outward) 
         AND del_date < DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonthO + 1, @Outward) and isDelivered = 1
      left outer join RS_Sell_Order_Mapping as sm on 
          sm.sell_order_no = s.sell_order_no     
GROUP BY cte.TheMonth
)Z
```

Comment: Not withstanding the other issues, why declare the same `common table expression` multiple times?

Comment: thank you very much Mr. DigitalDNA. I really appreciate Your effort. My issue is resolved but I sm getting the o/p for both of the table in the single column & i want it in the diffrent column's what should i do???? to achieve this –

Comment: i've made an edit over @sgeddes Query because i can't edit theirs. Maybe this is that you need. Thanks also to sgeddes to have a better approach than me.

Comment: I am getting Error as Column 'Z.TheMonth' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Friend I got the solution thank's alot for your efforts

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to put a group by ath the ond of sgeddes query sorry :P